# Standardizing two Hashes to include same keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I am looking to graph multiple series in a highcharts graph.  I have the following two variables

```
   first = {5 => [dates in here], 6 => [dates in here], etc}
   second = {4 => [dates in here], 5 => [dates in here], etc}
```

The keys are the number associated with the months (4, April, 5, May, etc.)

The problem I am running into is that The two hashes may not always have the same corresponding months.  So when I am graphing the data the first[5] is graphing next to second[4], and first[6] is graphing next to second[5] etc.

How can I standardize the two variables so that they always contain the same keys even if it would look something like this:

```
   first = {4 => [no data], 5 => [dates in here], 6 => [dates in here], etc}
   second = {4 => [dates in here], 5 => [dates in here], 6 => [no data], etc}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first_keys = first.keys
second_keys = second.keys
keys = first_keys + second_keys

keys.uniq.each do |key|
  first[key]  = [] if first[key].nil?
  second[key] = [] if second[key].nil?
end
```

Comment: Alternatively `first[key] ||= []` or `first[key] = [] unless first.key?(key)`

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways to do this as it's rather open-ended, but you could create a common `keys` array from the two hashes and iterate over that assigning `nil` to the hash at that `key`. I would do it specifically like this

```
keys = (first.keys + second.keys).uniq
keys.each do |key|
  first[key] ||= nil
  second[key] ||= nil
end
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland But if you explicitly set it it to `nil` that key shows up in `keys` and iteration whereas if you don't, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As you are graphing the data, presumably with months on the x-axis and days on the y-axis, I think it would be most convenient to iterate over a range of months that provides a minimal cover of the keys (months) contained in both hashes.

```
data = [{ 5=>[3, 5, 11, 24], 6=>[1, 7, 13, 30], 2=>[4, 13, 18, 29] },
        { 4=>[6, 9, 19, 26], 5=>[4, 8, 11, 22], 1=>[1, 19, 22, 24] }]

month_range = Range.new(*data.reduce([]) { |arr, h| arr | h.keys }.minmax)
  #=> 1..6
```

Note

```
a = data.reduce([]) { |arr, h| arr | h.keys }
  #=> [5, 6, 2, 4, 1]
b = a.minmax
  #=> [1, 6]
Range.new(*b)
  #=> Range.new(*[1, 6]) => Range.new(1, 6) => 1..6
```

I've represented the input as an arbitrary array of hashes, should there be more than two.

For graphing, simply iterate over `month_range`, then for each month `m` iterate over the elements `h` of `data` (hashes) for which `h` has a key `m`, and plot the days in `h[m]`, if any (not "no data").

```
month_range.each do |m|
  data.each do |h|
    <plot h[m]> if h.has_key?(m) && h[m].any?
  end
end
```